# Why is the cycle endless?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hi guys!

I want to switch to UE4 and am now trying to repeat the function of finding a way by waypoints, it works well in Unity, but there were problems in C ++. the function turned out with an infinite loop, as I understand it, openList cannot become empty. my c ++ knowledge is not enough to solve the problem. I will be glad of any help!

```
TArray<FVector> UWaypointsPathfinding::GetPath(UWaypoint* startNode, UWaypoint* goalNode)
{
    UWaypoint* beginNode = startNode;
    set<UWaypoint*> openList;
    vector<UWaypoint*> closedList;

    openList.insert(startNode);
    startNode->previous = nullptr;
    startNode->distance = 0;


    while (!openList.empty())
    {
        startNode = *openList.begin();
        openList.erase(openList.begin());


        float dist = startNode->distance;
        closedList.push_back(startNode);
        if(startNode == goalNode) break;

        int l = startNode->nearest.Num();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            UWaypoint* node = startNode->nearest[i]->FindComponentByClass<UWaypoint>();
            if(find(closedList.begin(),closedList.end(),node) != closedList.end() || openList.find(node) != openList.end())
                continue;

            node->previous = startNode;
            node->distance = dist + FVector::Dist(node->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation(), startNode->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());
            node->distance += FVector::Dist(node->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation(), goalNode->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());

            openList.insert(startNode);
        }


    }

    // create path...

    return TArray<FVector>();
}
```

supposedly the problem is in this piece

```
if(startNode == goalNode) break;

int l = startNode->nearest.Num();
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
   UWaypoint* node = startNode->nearest[i]->FindComponentByClass<UWaypoint>();
   if(find(closedList.begin(),closedList.end(),node) != closedList.end() || openList.find(node) != openList.end())
                        continue;

    node->previous = startNode;
    node->distance = dist + FVector::Dist(node->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation(), startNode->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());
    node->distance += FVector::Dist(node->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation(), goalNode->GetOwner()->GetActorLocation());

    openList.insert(startNode);
}
```

Comment: If this is rather a C++ problem then you might simplify/resemble your code in a [mcve], reducing the noise and making it clean and compilable/runnable for everybody (e.g. in an online-compiler). IMHO, this would raise the chances for a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Scheff I'm not sure there may be a problem in the methods UE4 that I use

Comment: This seems like a great problem for a debugger! Take 10-20mins to learn it and I promise you will find the problem in moments. Also, I would always recommend using unreal containers over the std lib for performance as well as ironically, compatibility (unless they're need to interface with a 3rd party api). Also it's worth thinking a little about performance. There are a few missteps the compiler will probably sort out but there is a metric ton of avoidable dynamic allocation & calls to `FindComponentByClass`.

Comment: If you face a problem where you are uncertain about its origin, try to separate possible reasons. First, resemble it in C++. Make sure that your algorithm works as expected (and why and in which edge cases it may break). Debugging a C++ console appl. e.g. in VS or with gdb is probably much easier than with UE4 around. If you are sure about your algorithm and it still doesn't work in UE4 than you may start to investigate into this further.

Comment: Side note, don't use STL types in UE4. Use UE4 types, e.g. `TSet` and `TArray` instead of `std::set` and `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

The logic is strange so this is a mistype probably. 
You insert startNode to openList at the beginning, then erase it in the loop and insert again. So the openList will always have a single member startNode and all cycles are identical. 
Perhaps you meant `openList.insert(node);` instead of `openList.insert(startNode);` at the last line of the loop?